# jQuery adaptive form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a dynamic form that I need to validate user side. I don't require that they fill out every part of the form, but if they fill out one column of a row, then they have to fill out the remaining columns. For example, if they fill out the CC #, they are required to also fill out the amount, approval, and the date, but if they don't fill out anything, then they're free to click on 'next'. This is to ensure that all the required information is gathered. Any suggestions on how I can do this?

To save space, I've put the code on JS Fiddle. This is just to show what type of format my form/table is in.

http://jsfiddle.net/8z3Sy/

Comment: Is jQuery 1.3 a requirement or can you upgrade?

Comment: It's not a requirement. I'm just using whatever I downloaded a few weeks ago.

Comment: Well, jQuery 1.8 is out. 1.3 is over 2 1/2 years old so you'll run into compatibility issues with most plugins. Beyond that, try taking a look at jQuery Validation: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 0):

One idea is, on your click event compare the # of fields with the # of empty fields for each row.

```
var fields = $(this).find('td input').length; 
var filled_fields =  $(this).find('td input:text').filter(function() { return this.value != ""; }).length; 

if (fields == filled_fields || filled_fields == 0) 
{
    //Continue on with the next table (all row data is filled out OR all row data is empty)
}
else 
{
    //There is a field missing on the pertaining row
    //Stop Propagation
}
```

Comment: This really puts me in the right direction. The method that you mentioned doesn't exactly do what I wanted, so I tried counting the number of filled inputs each column has and comparing them. If they're not equal, that means that not every column for each filled row is completed. This causes some issues still though, and I'm not exactly sure how to get around it.